# How many monoids of order three are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, monoid

http://oeis.org/A058129

In the above link we can see the answer is 7. I have tried counting these and don't get 7. I am not sure what I am doing wrong so could someone go through counting these step by step?

Comment: This might be a useful note to whoever tries to explain this to me. I get **more** than 7 which means that I am missing some of the logic for eliminating choices.

Comment: What monoids are you counting? Maybe you could list them out.

Comment: I think there are $11$ distinct associative multiplication tables for the monoid $\{1,2,3\}$ in which $1$ is the identity. Four pairs of these are isomorphic under the mapping that interchanges $2$ and $3$, and the remaining $3$ are fixed by this mapping. So the total number of isomorphism classes of monoids is $7$.

Comment: I just learned what monoids were yesterday so bear with me. For starters, how did you arrive to 11 distinct associative multiplication tables?

Comment: I just wrote them all down. First suppose $2\times 2=1$. Then, for $2 \times (2 \times 3) = (2 \times 2) \times 3$ to hold, we must have $2 \times 3 = 3$, similarly $3 \times 2 = 3$, and $(3 \times 3) \times 2 = 3 \times (3 \times 2)$ forces $3 \times 3 = 3$. Next suppose $2 \times 2 = 2$. This is more complicated, because $2 \times 3$ can be $2$ or $3$, and you find $7$ tables altogether with $2 \times 2 = 2$, and then a further $3$ with $2 \times 2 = 3$. Try it!

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ be a monoid with three elements. Let $G$ be its group of units (elements which have an inverse) and let $I$ be its minimal ideal. Note that if $|I| = 1$, then $M$ has a zero.
Let denote by $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$.

1. If $M = G = I$, then $M = C_3$. Otherwise, $G$ and $I$ are disjoint.
2. If $|G| = 2$ and $|I| = 1$ then $M = C_2 \cup \{0\}$.
3. If $|G| = 1$ and $|I| = 1$, then $M = \{1, a, 0\}$ and two cases occur: either $aa = a$ or $aa = 0$.
4. If $|G| = 1$ and $|I| = 2$, then three possibilities occur: $I = C_2$, $I = \{a, b\}$ with $aa = ba = a$ and $bb = ab = b$ or $I = \{a, b\}$ with $aa = ab = a$ and $bb = ba = b$.

Altogether, this gives 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7 possibilities.